# Regex syntax to deal with carriage returns in php

Tags: php, regex

I've been working on coming up with regex syntax to deal with making certain string patterns into clickable links from a form.  Carriage returns are causing problems with my regex pattern and need some help understanding how to omit them.  As an example, if I enter this text into my text area;

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.google.com
www.google.com
google.com
```

This is the output before my regex pattern sees it;

```
http://www.google.com\r\nhttp://www.google.com\r\nwww.google.com\r\ngoogle.com
```

I need to be able to remove the \r\n characters from the hyperlinks.  My regex looks like this;

```
function make_links_clickable($message)
    {
    return preg_replace('!(((.*www\.)?(f|ht)tp(s)?://)?[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="http://$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $message);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to remove any leading \r\n characters in regex?

Comment: Why do you need to remove them? Your regexp doesn't match them.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to split on new lines, and run your regex on each piece. Observe:

```
function make_links_clickable($message)
{
       $result = array();
       foreach(explode(PHP_EOL,$message) as $m)
       {
           $result[] = preg_replace('!(((.*www\.)?(f|ht)tp(s)?://)?[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="http://$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $m);
       }
       return join(PHP_EOL,$result);
}
```

Alternatively you could use [preg_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php)

Comment: Shouldn't he split on `"\r\n"`?

Comment: Why is this necessary? The regexp doesn't match across newlines.

Comment: @Byron - When I try the syntax in your solution, it kicks back an error (complaining about 'in' in the foreach).  Any ideas?

Comment: @Kimomaru Sorry using C# syntax in php wont work :) try it now